# how to fix error in angular when add primeng TreeModule

Tags: angular, tree, primeng

my AppModule

```
import {TreeModule} from 'primeng/tree';
.
.
.
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    TreeModule
  ],
```

when I add TreeModule or other in app.module.ts these errors are occured
and errors

```
    node_modules/primeng/tree/tree.d.ts:194:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/wamp64/www/primeTree/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration'.
    
    194     static ɵmod: i0.ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration<TreeModule, [typeof Tree, typeof UITreeNode], [typeof i1.CommonModule, typeof i2.SharedModule, typeof i3.RippleModule, typeof i4.ScrollerModule], [typeof Tree, typeof i2.SharedModule, typeof i4.ScrollerModule]>;
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/primeng/tree/tree.d.ts:195:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/wamp64/www/primeTree/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectorDeclaration'.
    
    195     static ɵinj: i0.ɵɵInjectorDeclaration<TreeModule>;
```

my package.json is

```
{
  "name": "prime-tree",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "~10.2.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "primeicons": "^5.0.0",
    "primeng": "^14.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
```

I added primeng and primeicons
also I try to use other module like ToastModule and errors occured again
I use guide of primefaces website to run tree but is not work

Comment: Try to remove node_modules / upgrade angular version

Comment: Downgrade `PrimeNg` to the same version number of your Angular version will solved.